# How to print list of absolute URLs in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I want to print a list of absolute URLs in a Spring JSP, for an internal user to pick from.  However, the page is rendered with the current URL prepended.

For Example I want to a link to **www.anothersite.com**, but the links comes out as **http://localhost:8080/myapp/www.anothersite.com** on the page

What am I doing wrong?  Both lines below have the same result.

```
<c:forEach items="${listAppURLForm}" var="nextURL">
    <li>
        <a href=<c:out value="${nextURL.link}"></c:out>>${nextURL.link}</a>
        <a href=${nextURL.link}>${nextURL.link}</a>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the URL in the debugger? What is the code that generates `listAppURLForm`? There's a strong possibility your URLs actually are `http://localhost...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a misconception. An URL like `www.example.com` is definitely not an absolute URL. The [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) is completely missing. You need to prepend the URL with the desired scheme to make it really an absolute URL, like so `http://www.example.com`.

If you can't edit the URLs directly in the list, then you'd need to prefix it in HTML instead.

```html
<a href="http://${nextURL.link}">${nextURL.link}</a>
```

You might want to perform a `${fn:startsWith()}` check beforehand to prevent duplicate schemes.